# Exclude custom post type from search conflict with get_posts

Tags: theme-development

I want to hide my custom post type from search results. So, I followed the codex and used:

`exclude_from_search => 'true'` while registering my custom post type.

That hides the custom post type and it does not appear in search results any more.

But now I am unable to load posts using `get_posts` but they appear fine with `WP_Query`. I wonder why it is happening.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how exactly `get_posts()` fails for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_posts()` uses `WP_Query`, so you are probably providing wrong arguments, it's worth mentioning that the function has [some default arguments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Default_Usage).

This should get all posts of the CPT `myCPT`:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'myCPT',
    'post_status'    => 'any',
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code?

```
function excludePages($query) {
   if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'post');
   }
   return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','excludePages');
```